# Error trying to add Ebean to PlayFramework 2.5 using IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework, ebean

I'm starting to work with PlayFramework and trying to make a simple project using Java + Mysql + Ebean.

It was supposed to be an easy configuration but is becoming a nightmare...

I follow the official documentation and I have no problem creating a simple project with a Mysql database. Problems come when trying to add Ebean plugin. I don't know what I'm doing wrong becouse I'm following the official docs, so I put my config files here and the compiling error hoping that someone can help.

plugins.sbt

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at   "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.10")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.0.0")
```

build.sbt

```
name := "pruebasplay"

version := "1.0"

lazy val `testplay` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( javaJdbc ,  cache , javaWs)

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test <+=  baseDirectory ( _ /"target/web/public/test" )  

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

routesGenerator := StaticRoutesGenerator

libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.36"
```

Theoretically this two config files are the ones involved to add Ebean, but when I add the Ebean config lines the project doesn't compile and show this log:

```
va.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sbt/compiler/IC$Result
    at com.typesafe.play.sbt.enhancer.Imports$.<init> .   (PlayEnhancer.scala:13)
    at com.typesafe.play.sbt.enhancer.Imports$.<clinit>(PlayEnhancer.scala)
    at com.typesafe.play.sbt.enhancer.PlayEnhancer$.<init>(PlayEnhancer.scala:22)
    at com.typesafe.play.sbt.enhancer.PlayEnhancer$.<clinit>(PlayEnhancer.scala)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
...
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this running the application with activator through the terminal instead of using Intellij IDE.

```
$ activator run
```

So I don't know why it wasn't working with the IDE, maybe some wrong configuration...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you need to edit `conf/application.conf`.

Please try to add below.

`ebean.default = "models.*"`